# Can we fire a database query in config/constants.php file to make constants dynamic? (Php Codeignitor)

Tags: sql, codeigniter, dynamic, constants, config

I have tried to place this at the bottom of the config/config.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();

$query = $db->get('constants');
$result = $query->result();

foreach( $result as $row)
{
    $config[$row->title] = $row->value;
}
```

but it is throwing this error:
An uncaught Exception was encountered

**Type: Error
Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found
Filename: E:\xampp74\htdocs\jrvs\system\core\CodeIgniter.php
Line Number: 369**

Please suggest me some solution for this. If this is not possible then what else we can do to make constants dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**constants.php** is the very first file that is loaded in **Codeigniter.php** so you can't use the instance of codeigniter in this file cause if hasn't been loaded yet and of course you can't rely on hooks because it loads after this file has been loaded and constants had been defined so!

You best option is to manually connect to your db in top of this file or in index.php and query what you need then use the values in define.

Comment: Database connection doesn`t seem possible in top of that file. Can you please eloborate how to do it?

Comment: @NidhiVala i meant custom db connection (do it yourself with a custom script), i said you cannot use any codeigniter functionality yet in this file.